# multiple div heights to match single tallest div height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a layout with multiple divs side by side and the will be populated with random text in each div. Is it possible to have the height of the tallest get matched by the rest of the divs regardless of the amount of text they have?

Basically I need the divs to be `height:auto;` and lets say, the second div has so much text that it's height becomes about 200px and the rest of the divs only have enough text to make their height about 100px. Instead of the 200px div being the tallest the rest of the divs extend to match the 200px div and create a uniform look.

Is anything like possible purely using CSS or would JavaScript need to be used?

Sorry if this sounds confusing, I would post an example picture but I don't have enough points (boo!)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F84zq/)

Comment: This is a VERY common question. Check out this explanation. http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: Oh wow, didn't think it was THAT common! Just quickly skimmed over it and unless I miss read it, this article assumes you know what div will be the tallest, just the way he has applied percentages to them. I need my divs to know which has the most text and adjust to match the tallest.

Comment: No, never mind, I think it's dynamic :)

Comment: This may prove useful too: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 0):

You could lay them out like a table as in [this updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F84zq/2/)

```
.container {
    display:table; 
    position:relative; 
    border-spacing:20px;
}
.block {
    display:table-cell;
    position:relative;
    width:190px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:FFF;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align: center;
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
    font-size:small;
}
```